Why does the fictional character use the pronoun "thou" instead of "you"?
In the novel "Emma" by Jane Austen, Mr. K says:

“Another thing must be taken into consideration too—Mrs. Elton does not
talk to Miss Fairfax as she speaks of her. We all know the difference between
the pronouns he or she and thou, the plainest spoken amongst us; we all feel
the influence of a something beyond common civility in our personal
intercourse with each other—a something more early implanted. We cannot
give any body the disagreeable hints that we may have been very full of the
hour before. We feel things differently. And besides the operation of this, as a
general principle, you may be sure that Miss Fairfax awes Mrs. Elton by her
superiority both of mind and manner; and that, face to face, Mrs. Elton treats
her with all the respect which she has a claim to. Such a woman as Jane
Fairfax probably never fell in Mrs. Elton’s way before—and no degree of
vanity can prevent her acknowledging her own comparative littleness in
action, if not in consciousness.”

All the characters are the gentry. The action takes place in Surrey at the very beginning of the XIX century. They never use "thou" instead of "you". It seems like Mr. K. wants to somehow make his idea more clear. But what does he mean by this?

It's thou, not 'thow'. I'm not sure why Mr Knightley uses it, as it must have already been virtually obsolete (except for the Bible and Book of Common Prayer). He seems to be making a distinction between slandering someone behind their back and yet being polite when addressing them in person.

@KateBunting - 'thee' and 'thou' persisted very late among the Quakers, well into the 20th century, and some still use what they call 'plain speech' now.

Nobody 'uses' the pronoun thou. It is merely said that 'we all know the difference between the pronouns he or she and thou'. That is just another way of saying that 'we all know the rules of politeness and good manners'

@MichaelHarvey - I know, but I didn't think Quakerism was particularly relevant to social life in Highbury in the Regency era!

This isn't really about learning English, but about literary analysis and historical English. Better suited to another stack exchange.

My mother, no Quaker, born 1920, used to say of dishonest people that they 'didn't know the difference between mine and thine'.

@JamesK I'd say "what on earth is 'thou'" is on-topic—historical yes, but so commonly encountered as to be relevant to the learner. But I suppose I should have checked for a duplicate before answering.

@JamesK As to literary analysis, I may have let myself fall into it, but to my mind the question falls under "you may ask about the meaning of a sentence or passage you find in literature"; the OP is just having a hard time parsing the text.

In modern usage, English has only one second-person pronoun, "you." In many other languages, there is a "formal" and an "informal" second-person pronoun, like "usted" vs "tu" in Spanish or "vous" vs "tu" in French.
English used to make this distinction too, before about 1800. "Thee/thou" was the informal version of "you." (You can see a bit of a cognate with "tu.") You would use it with people of lower social standing or with intimate friends, while you would use "you" with superiors and strangers. In Shakespeare's Twelfth Night, one character tells another to write an angry and insulting letter challenging someone to a fight, and "if thou 'thou'-est him some thrice, it shall not be amiss." (This can be confusing for us since to our ears the archaic "thou" sounds "fancy" and therefore formal, but in fact it's the opposite.)
Already in Austen's time, "thou" was not in common use, so this passage is already using an "old-fashioned" example to talk about social respect or disrespect. The point is that Jane Fairfax speaks of Mrs. Elton with conversational markers of formality and respect, while Mrs. Elton speaks of Jane with familiarity or condescension (the way one might have used "thou" a century earlier). Although Mrs. Elton may have some claim to social elevation (she is married and claims to have money, while Jane is a single orphan with limited money), the other characters don't agree that this elevation is enough to make her behavior mannerly. (It is strongly hinted, in fact, that she is lying about her background and might be simply claiming more prestige than is supported by facts.)

Thank you for the explanation and a very useful link!
I think that Mr. K. means familiarity.  Mrs. Elton is known for familiarity when speaking about Mr.Knightley just as "Knightley" without Mr.

@Natalie And Mr. Knightley is indeed of a much higher social standing than any of them, though he doesn't rub anyone's nose in it. For Mrs. Elton to be familiar with Jane is simply unkind or ungenerous; to do so with Mr. Knightley is a truly embarrassing mistake.

I would dwell on Mr Knightley and his social position but it seems to be beyond any allowed topic here.  But still, I have received a meaningfull answer! Thank you very much!

@Natalie Questions about literary aspects can be asked at the Literature SE site
